# How to get and display the entire html url on screen through httpc: request in erlang?

Tags: erlang

do

```
process (Url) ->
  {Status, Header, Body} = httpc:request(get, {Url, []}, [], []),
 io:format(Body).
```

no output html to Body to display

how to get and display the entire html url on screen through httpc:request in erlang?

Answer (score 1):

`io:format/2` works kind of like C's `printf`: you need a format string.

```
io:format("Body: ~p\n", [Body]).
```

[Documentation](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/io.html?i=3&search=io%3aformat#format/2)

Comment: Error in process <0.41.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,no_scheme}},[{test,process,1,[{file,"test.erl"},{line,30}]}]}